# $x$ generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^* \implies$ $x$ generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, arithmetic

As it's indicated in the title, I have to show that

> $x$ generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^* \implies$ $x$ generator of  $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$, $p \neq 2$.

I'm not sure of my proof, it's why I post it here and I hope you will be able to enlighten me if it's okay or not ! :)

My proof :

We know that ($\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic. Let's $\overline{q}$ be a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$. So  $\overline{x} = \overline{q}^m$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. But $\overline{q}$ is as well generating ($\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$, and we have : $x = q^m + kp^n$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, as $n \geq 2$, we have : $x = q'^m [p^2]$ ($\overline{x} = \overline{q}^m$, but this time mod $p^2$).

On the other side, we know that $\mathrm{ord}(\overline{x}) = p(p-1)$ over $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$ and $\overline{q}$ is generating $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$, so we should have $\gcd(m,p(p-1))=1$ (otherwise $x$ is not a generator over $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$).

From here, as $\gcd(p,p-1)=1$, we have $\gcd(m,p)=1, \gcd(m,p-1)=1$, and then $\gcd(m,p^n(p-1))=1$. So, $\mathrm{ord}(\overline{x}) = \mathrm{ord}(\overline{q}) = p^n(p-1)$ over $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$, and we have the result.

Is it right or not ? :)

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

The proof looks reasonable, but you should clean up and clarify a few things: what is $q'$ in your first paragraph?  Why exactly does $\gcd(m, p(p-1))\neq 1$ imply that $x$ is not a generatator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\ast$?

Also, I believe in the last paragraph you use $n$ when you mean $n-1$.

Comment: It's a typo mistake for $q'$, I mean $q$, sorry. If $d = gcd(m,p(p-1)) \neq 1$, as $x=q^m$ over $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$, and $q$ is a generator for $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$ (here by q, I mean $\overline{q}$ over $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$), we have : $ord(x) = \frac{p(p-1)}{pgcd(m, p(p-1))} = \frac{p(p-1)}{d}$ and then as $d \neq 1$, $x$ is not a generator cause its order is not the order of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^*$). For the last paragraph, yes it's a mistake, it's $n-1$.

Comment: @ChocoSavour Looks like a good proof with those fixes.  Personally, I think a counting argument is the simplest: there are exactly $\varphi(\varphi(p^2)) = (p-1)\varphi(p-1)$ generators of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\ast$, and $p^{n-2}(p-1) \varphi(p-1)$ lifts mod $p^n$.  But there are $\varphi(\varphi(p^n)) = p^{n-2}(p-1) \varphi(p-1)$ generators of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\ast$, each of which is a lift.